# Error : Connection Refused. Upload file to Asp Web Api

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I'm developing cross platform app using Xamarin forms. I want to select and upload an image to ASP Web Api's folder. I can select image but I'm getting

> Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)

when I'm trying to upload. I am using VS Android Emulator to test the application.

```
private async void UploadFile_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    content.Add(new StreamContent(_mediaFile.GetStream()),
        "\"file\"",
        $"\"{_mediaFile.Path}\"");

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var uploadServiceBaseAddress = "http://localhost:55678/api/Files/Upload";

    var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(uploadServiceBaseAddress, content);

    RemotePathLabel.Text = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

}
```

I inserted breakpoints to see the exception and it occurs on

```
var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(uploadServiceBaseAddress, content);
```

What is the problem exactly in my code?

Comment: Can you get the inner exception/aggregate exception details?

Comment: try using the IP or FQDN, not localhost

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said you are trying to load file from localhost. In this case it is an address of your emulator which doesn't make sense as your file is not there (emulator and PC have different IP addresses). Make sure your emulator has assigned IP address on the same network as your PC and use PC address to load your file